# New to coding: HTML/Javascript Help: Mouseover Trail Effect

Tags: javascript, html

I have started creating a website and found this cool mouse trail effect, however, when I move my mouse over the navigation menu and links, if the effect is still on, I cannot click on the menu link or other links. Is there any way to code this where it only activates on the area where there are no elements - menus, links, etc. - on the website?

It's hard to explain, but here's the website: [www.danceden.co.uk](http://www.danceden.co.uk), and you will see what I mean when you move the mouse over.

Mouse Trail Coding:

```
<pre>
    <bottom>
        <script type="javascript" src="http://htmlfreecodes.com/userdata/0118/zibasazi/ziba.js"></script>
        <a target="_blank" href="http://www.htmlfreecodes.com" style="font-size: 8pt; text-decoration: none"></a>
    </bottom>
</pre>
```

I'm also using GoDaddy Site Builder.

Comment: <bottom><script type="javascript" src="http://htmlfreecodes.com/userdata/0118/zibasazi/ziba.js"></script><a target="_blank" href="http://www.htmlfreecodes.com" style="font-size: 8pt; text-decoration: none"></a></bottom>

Comment: please add code to your question,  never as a comment.

Comment: @Bosworth99 He was trying.  Just a little formatting issue is all.

Comment: Sorry, new to this site as well

Comment: not an answer - but a comment / caution. Take care when implementing effects such as this mouse trail effect. Firstly - not all people will like it, but more importantly, you have to think about the effect of seeing this through all mouse movements through the user expereince in the site. effects like this tend to get old VERY quickly and worsens the user experience of the site. I recommend clients to move away from such effects as it may be fine for a little while on the first page load, but if the effect continues, it becomes distracting and over stated. Just my 2 cents worth for the UI /UX.